# what can I do with the 'Declare parents' of Spring-aop

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

**I know how to config the Introduction aop in Spring**

It is esay,here some codes:

```
//my business serice
public class MyService {

    public void doWork() {
         System.out.println("doWork");
   }
}

// the Introduction interface and its Implementation 
public interface Someable {
     public void method();
}

public class SomeImp implements Someable {
@Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("method");
     }
}
```

And the spring xml:

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:aspect id="TestAspect">
        <aop:declare-parents types-matching="foo.bar.MyService+"
                             implement-interface="foo.bar.Someable"
                             default-impl="foo.bar.SomeImp"></aop:declare-parents>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Then the main code:

```
public class HelloApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
    MyService myService = (MyService) context.getBean("myService");
    myService.doWork();
    ((Someable) (myService)).method();
    }
}
```

**What I want to know is :**

What can I do in my SomeImp class,

which design is the way for me to use with this aop advice,

I just do not understand what is the purpose to add interface to a service using the AOP-Way

Can someone apply some real story in your project?